# What is the difference between a p element and a paragraph with text?

Tags: html, language-lawyer, semantics

I have read [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69997152/18582964) but still have some confusion and asked.

### Premise

According to the HTML Standard, the [`p` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) represents a [paragraph](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#paragraph).

> ##### 4.4.1 The p element
>
> The p element represents a [paragraph](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#paragraph).

And the HTML Standard's explanation for [paragraphs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#paragraph) reads as follows:

> A paragraph is typically a run of phrasing content that forms a block of text with one or more sentences that discuss a particular topic, as in typography, but can also be used for more general thematic grouping. For instance, an address is also a paragraph, as is a part of a form, a byline, or a stanza in a poem.

Here, according to NOTE, the `p` element is one of several that represent a paragraph. Also, the term paragraph as defined in this section is used for more than just the definition of the `p` element.

> **The term paragraph as defined in this section is used for more than just the definition of the `p` element.** The paragraph concept defined here is used to describe how to interpret documents. **The `p` element is merely one of several ways of marking up a paragraph.**

Furthermore, the following HTML considers [text](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#text-content) to be a paragraph and states that there are five paragraphs.

> ```html
> <section>
>  <h1>My Cats</h1>
>  You can play with my cat simulator.
>  <object data="cats.sim">
>   To see the cat simulator, use one of the following links:
>   <ul>
>    <li><a href="cats.sim">Download simulator file</a>
>    <li><a href="https://sims.example.com/watch?v=LYds5xY4INU">Use online simulator</a>
>   </ul>
>   Alternatively, upgrade to the Mellblom Browser.
>  </object>
>  I'm quite proud of it.
> </section>
> ```
>
> 1. The paragraph that says "You can play with my cat simulator. object I'm quite proud of it.", where object is the object element.
> 2. The paragraph that says "To see the cat simulator, use one of the following links:".
> 3. The paragraph that says "Download simulator file".
> 4. The paragraph that says "Use online simulator".
> 5. The paragraph that says "Alternatively, upgrade to the Mellblom Browser.".

### Question 1

The five paragraphs shown in the code contain [text](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#text-content). Does this indicate that semantically [text](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#text-content) also represents a paragraph?

### Question 2

The description of the `p` element says that the `p` element represents a [paragraph](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#paragraph).
However, the paragraph section says "the `p` element is one of several that represent a paragraph" and "the term paragraph as defined in this section is used for more than just the definition of the `p` element.

In other words, the paragraph section does not clarify what kind of paragraph the `p` element represents. What is the exact definition of the `p` element?

Comment: This question is actually somewhat weird considering that it is not really related to programming, rather than linguistics? I think that in terms of programming all that matters about `<p>` is the fact it's just a block element with margins

Answer (score 0):

**question 1:** yes

**question 2:**
The p element creates a paragraph, the contiguous section of longer text. However, in HTML, p can be used for any type of contiguous content to be grouped, for example, images or form fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply regard `p` elements as paragraphs of "plain text content", as opposed to headers, lists, quotes etc. for which there are separate tags in HTML.

Of course you can also create a paragraph using a `div` or `span` tags defining their styling with CSS (using classes or IDs) and thereby making them look like regular `p` paragraphs. Even the "non-paragraphs" in your example which are basically formed by being between two other tags without having a tag of their own as delimiters will look like `p` text if their *parent*  container has CSS rules (or just default settings) that is equal or similar to `p` tags.

But semantically, only a `p` tag is "regular" text content (i.e. not having a function like being a header, part of a list, a blockquote or whatever HTML supplies tags for). If you think in terms of acessibility or SEO, this makes a difference, even if you don't *see* it.